# MySQL inner join help - want to include rows where there is no match

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have  a few tables I am joining in a look-up.

(PET)

```
| id | owner_id |  pet_name   | size |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |    1     |   Sparky    |  L   |
| 2  |    1     |    Spot     |  L   |
| 3  |    3     |   FooFoo    |  M   |
| 4  |    3     |    Barky    |  L   |
| 5  |    3     |    Jeb      |  S   |
```

(OWNER)

```
| id |  owner_name  |
--------------------
| 1  |    Jeff      |
| 2  |   (Kathy)    |
| 3  |    Tom       |
```

When I do an inner join like this:

```
SELECT 

OWNER.id, OWNER.owner_name, PET.pet_name, PET.size

FROM OWNER

INNER JOIN PET ON PET.owner_id = OWNER.id
```

I get a result like this:

```
| id |  owner_name  |  pet_name   | size |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     Jeff     |   Sparky    |  L   |
| 1  |     Jeff     |    Spot     |  L   |
| 3  |     Tom      |   FooFoo    |  M   |
| 3  |     Tom      |    Barky    |  L   |
| 3  |     Tom      |    Jeb      |  S   |
```

**Kathy** is not in the result. I understand why. But I want Kathy to be in the result.
I want all owners to show up regardless of if they have a pet or not - and the ones that do merge as they have with this join.

How do I get all of the OWNER table to display all owners in a join with the PET table - regardless of if they have a pet in PET table?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: The fix is what G-Nugget suggested (and the answer from raheel shan).  Replace the keyword `INNER` with the keyword `LEFT`. Voila!

Answer (score 7):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER

```
SELECT
  OWNER.id,
  OWNER.owner_name,
  PET.pet_name,
  PET.size
FROM OWNER
  LEFT JOIN PET
    ON PET.owner_id = OWNER.id
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your join a LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT OWNER.id, OWNER.owner_name, PET.pet_name, PET.size
  FROM OWNER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PET 
    ON PET.owner_id = OWNER.id
```

Remember that a left **outer** returns all records on the "left" side of your join even if there is no matching record on the "right" side of the join, returning "null" values for those field(s). An "inner" join, as you can see, *only* returns records where there are matches on both the left AND right sides.

Hope that gives you a push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Use an Outer Join

```
SELECT 

OWNER.id, OWNER.owner_name, PET.pet_name, PET.size

FROM OWNER

Outer JOIN PET ON PET.owner_id = OWNER.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You're identifying the tables in the wrong order. Start with the one you want all the results from, and then left join the other table to it. That way you're looking at owners and their dogs, rather than dogs and their owners.

```
FROM OWNER
LEFT JOIN PET
ON PET.owner_id = OWNER.id
```